# Using .htaccess to fix multiple broken links in my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've recently bulk imported 14,000 items into a joomla K2 database and now realised the 'external URL' field required an http:// in front of the URL!  So all the external links on my site are now going to http://www.example.com/www.externalurl.com instead of http://www.externalurl.com

I've worked out that I can probably use the .htaccess file to rewrite the incorrect URLs (which are going to a 404 error page at the moment) but I need a bit of help with the code for doing this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great - thanks.

**Update from comment:**

These suggestions unfortunately don't work - I think I should clarify my original question by saying I don't know what the "externalurl" is because it's different on various pages on the site.  I think I need something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/www\.([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ www\.$1 [L]
```

i.e. rewrite www.mywebsite.com/www.externalurl.com to www.externalurl.com

I tried this and it's not having any effect though...

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to redirect them externally, then the redirect match would be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/www\.externalurl\.com/?(.*) http://www.externalurl.com/$1
```

Jon Lin's redirect match will redirect them back to your own site.

Comment: Hi - this helped me solve the issue - I changed the code slightly and this works:  `RedirectMatch 301 ^/www\./?(.*) http://www.$1 `

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/www\.externalurl\.com/?(.*) /$1
```